# Reply button in mail_widget for Helpdesk Odoo 8

Tags: email, odoo-8, reply

I need to display reply button in mail_thread widget for help desk form view. There is only two buttons available ' Mark as to do' and Move to Inbox'. i need a 'Reply' button too. any solution??
IN js fild:

```
openerp.new_module = function(instance) {
instance.mail.RecordThread.include({
    init : function(parent, node) {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        this.node = _.clone(node);
        this.node.params = _.extend({
            'display_indented_thread' : 1,
            'show_reply_button' : true,

        }, this.node.params);

    }
});
};
```

in **openerp**.py

```
'js':'static/src/js/mail_thread_cus.js'],
```

Comment: extend the mail  widget

Comment: i tried this 
openerp.new_module = function(instance){
    //var module = instance.mail // loading the namespace of the 'sample' module
instance.mail.RecordThread.include({
    init: function (parent, node) {
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            this.node = _.clone(node);
            this.node.params = _.extend({
                'display_indented_thread': 1,
                'show_reply_button': true,

            }, this.node.params);

            }
         });
};

and in __openerp__.py
add 'js': ['static/src/js/mail_thread_cus.js'],
but nothg happend

Comment: you should add your code example as formatted code to your question (via `edit`). This improves the readability and increases the chance to get help.

Comment: i added my code into questions..